# How to use a Button to pass a time to Postgresql DB instead of a rails time_select box within a Form

Tags: javascript, ruby, html, css, ruby-on-rails-4

Im building out a CAD App in Rails 4 Ruby 2

What I would like to do is give the user a button to press on screen (as most users will be using touch screen computers) to log an on scene tine and clear scene time. Currently I have the default Rails time_select input boxes but decided to try to spice things up a bit.

I am wondering if this is at all possible and if so some ideas and help on how to achieve this.

A second question I have is how i could only display these time boxes if unit_2 - unit_4 has anything present in their respective DB Column. (I'll post pics below)

**my form looks like:**

```
<%= form_for(@call) do |f| %>
    <div class="panel panel-success" id="responding-box">
          <div class="panel-heading"><center><h4>Units Responding</h4></center></div>
          <table class="table">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th><center>Primary Responder</center></th>
                <th><center>Time On Scene</center></th>
                <th><center>Time Clear</center></th>
              </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td><center><%= f.collection_select(:user_id, User.all, :id, :employee_ident, {}, { :multiple => false } ) %></center></td>
                <td><center><%= f.time_select :unit_on_scene, {:include_blank => true, :default => nil} %></center></td>
                <td><center><%= f.time_select :unit_clear, {:include_blank => true, :default => nil} %></center></td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
          <br>
          <table class="table">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th><center>Backing Unit #1</center></th>
                <th><center>Time On Scene</center></th>
                <th><center>Time Clear</center></th>
              </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td><center><%= f.text_field :unit_2 %></center></td>
                <td><center><%= f.time_select :unit2_os, {:include_blank => true, :default => nil} %></center></td>
                <td><center><%= f.time_select :unit2_cl, {:include_blank => true, :default => nil} %></center></td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
          <br>
          <table class="table">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th><center>Backing Unit #2</center></th>
                <th><center>Time On Scene</center></th>
                <th><center>Time Clear</center></th>
              </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td><center><%= f.text_field :unit_3 %></center></td>
                <td><center><%= f.time_select :unit3_os, {:include_blank => true, :default => nil} %></center></td>
                <td><center><%= f.time_select :unit3_cl, {:include_blank => true, :default => nil} %></center></td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
          <br>
          <table class="table">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th><center>Backing Unit #3</center></th>
                <th><center>Time On Scene</center></th>
                <th><center>Time Clear</center></th>
              </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
              <tr>
              <td><center><%= f.text_field :unit_4 %></center></td> 
                <td><center><%= f.time_select :unit4_os, {:include_blank => true, :default => nil} %></center></td>
                <td><center><%= f.time_select :unit4_cl, {:include_blank => true, :default => nil} %></center></td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
```

**My controller looks like:**

```
class CallsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_call, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /calls
  # GET /calls.json
  def index
    @calls = Call.all
    @active_calls = @calls.select{|x| x.status == 'ACTIVE'}
    @pending_calls = @calls.select{|x| x.status == 'PENDING'}
  end

  # GET /calls/1
  # GET /calls/1.json
  def show

  end

  # GET /calls/new
  def new
    @call = Call.new
  end

  # GET /calls/1/edit
  def edit
    @call = Call.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /calls
  # POST /calls.json
  def create
    @call = Call.new(call_params)


    respond_to do |format|
      if @call.save
        format.html { redirect_to @call, notice: 'Call was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @call }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @call.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /calls/1
  # PATCH/PUT /calls/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @call.update(call_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @call, notice: 'Call was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @call }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @call.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /calls/1
  # DELETE /calls/1.json
  def destroy
    @call.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to calls_url, notice: 'Call was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_call
      @call = Call.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def call_params
      params.require(:call).permit(:call_time, :status, :primary_type, :secondary_type, :site, :address, :unit_1, :unit_2, :unit_3, :unit_4, :call_details, :unit_on_scene, :unit_clear, :call_num, :site_id, :user_id, :unit2_os, :unit2_cl, :unit3_os, :unit3_cl, :unit4_os, :unit4_cl)
    end
end
```

This is an Image of the section of the form I want to "Spice Up"

[image]

As you can see Each Unit has two time select boxes. I am looking to turn these into buttons that records the time and posts that to the respective table columns so i can then display them in the show.html.erb page.

As for the second question if there is nothing captured in the unit_2,3,4 boxes (string) then I would like those boxes / buttons hidden until they have been populated.

As of right now i am more than happy with just the buttons for the times. If you can help with one or both I would be much appreciative! Thanks in advance.

***EDIT: 
This is what i have added to my Rails Created Form.. when I click the button it follows the submit path and takes me to the show.html.erb page but dose not update the table to reflect the time.***

```
    <script>
    $('#unit_on_scene').on("click", function() {
    $('#unit_on_scene').val(Date());
    alert('unit_on_scene set to ' + $('#unit_on_scene').val());
    return false;
    })
    </script>

    <form action="" method="POST">
        <input type="hidden" id="unit_on_scene"></input>
        <button class="btn btn-nav btn-primary" id="unit_on_scene" type="submit">On Scene</button>
    </form>
    </center></td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question 1** should be easy to achieve with JavaScript. For example, you could have a button that is tied to a JavaScript event which sets a hidden input to the current time.

Example (using jQuery) Fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/k6emjoLt/

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#timeBtn').on("click", function(){
     $('#timeField').val(Date());
  })
</script>
```

**Question 2** is also straightforward. Create a variable in your controller for your view that will let you know if those fields have been populated.

Example (requires @unit2 to be set in controller)

```
<% if @unit2.present? %>
  <tr>
    <td><center><%= f.text_field :unit_2 %></center></td>
    <td><center><%= f.time_select :unit2_os, {:include_blank => true, :default => nil} %></center></td>
    <td><center><%= f.time_select :unit2_cl, {:include_blank => true, :default => nil} %></center></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Comment: so Java and JQuery i have no working knowledge of i am taking some very basic courses but not far through it at all yet.. how do i tie the button the the script and can i just put the script in the app.js file?

Comment: @ShawnWilson I would just put the script inline in the view since it is specific to that page using `<script>script goes here</script>.` Here is an example fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/k6emjoLt/

Comment: Awesome! I think that works just gonna hash it out! lats thing.. Seeing as the unit_2,3,4 call boxes are string what would be the best way to create the call for that? i have done some previous present? call in the past but the strings i was looking for were pre set and specific.. these strings could vary quite a bit and i just want it to load in anything is in there.

Comment: PS ill grant best answer as soon as i finish with the first button.

Comment: See Edit having an issue with script for button.

Comment: @ShawnWilson you'll need to modify your controller to look for the value from `param[:unit_on_scene]`, give that hidden input a `name="unit_on_scene"` and also add `type="text/javascript"` to your script tag.

Comment: Ok so the controller part is where it seems i am lacking here what exactly am i refrencing? lol.. im picking this up and its making sense but i cant wrap my head around this param[:unit_on_scene] in the controller.. i really do apologize!

Comment: @ShawnWilson to make it simpler, just rename your hidden field name/id to whatever the name/id was for the field it is replacing.

Comment: <input type="hidden" id="unit_on_scene"></input> is that not what this is?

Comment: @ShawnWilson you should have everything you need to research more and make it work, I would try something like `<input type="hidden" id="unit2_os" name="unit2_os"></input>` for Unit 2, you'll also need to modify the script to reference unit2_os instead of unit_on_scene.

Comment: I may have found something here.. should the .val(Date()); not be Time?asside from that everything ive done is letter for letter to what you have done. ill keep looking into it though cant be that crazy.. but im trying to pull a time into the DB not a date..